# Creating list of set values from a single value containing multiple value sets under one parenthesis

Tags: python, dataframe

so I currently have a column containing values like this:

```
d = {'col1': [LINESTRING(174.76028 -36.80417,174.76041 -36.80389, 175.76232 -36.82345)]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

and I am trying to make it so that I can:

1) apply a function to each of the numerical values and

2) end up with something like this.

```
d = {'col1': [LINESTRING], 'col2': [(174.76028, -36.80417),(174.76041 -36.80389), (175.76232 -36.82345)]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What is `LINESTRING` ?

Comment: I think its originally derived from Shapely, LineString, which ultimately is what's needed - LineString([(x,y),(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]). But I need to apply a function to those values before putting it through LineString.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. Note that `LineString` accepts an ordered collection of tuples as an input. See the [docs](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#linestrings) for more information.

We use `operator.attrgetter` to access the required attributes: `coords` and `__class__.__name__`.

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import attrgetter

class LineString():
    def __init__(self, list_of_coords):
        self.coords = list_of_coords
        pass

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [LineString([(174.76028, -36.80417), (174.76041, -36.80389), (175.76232, -36.82345)])]})

df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(attrgetter('coords'))
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(attrgetter('__class__')).apply(attrgetter('__name__'))

print(df)

         col1                                               col2
0  LineString  [(174.76028, -36.80417), (174.76041, -36.80389...
```